# How to write dash after question mark?

Tags: creative-writing, language

> I would have loved to buy her an expensive gift, but did I ever had money- for I was as poor as a beggar?

Is this sentence correct? I am having doubts about when to use a question mark. Is it acceptable in the end or immediately after money? I also don't want to remove the "for" conjunction. How can I restructure my sentence?

Comment: Probably better to ask this at https://ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The sentence is not correct.  There are grammatical errors, and the sentence is not structured as a native speaker would say or write it.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the question mark immediately after money and offset that comment in one of three ways: With m-dashes, with parentheses, or with a new sentence altogether. Probably best to rephrase, however.

But if you are learning written English and its usage, my advice is to break down that sentence into its individual clauses (I see three) and try to change the ordering to better effect.